# Can't transfer ownership of google drive txt files using gmail account and java API

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I am developing a multi user java web application which lets users list/share their google drive files between gmail accounts. I utilize oauth2 authorization code flow where user accessing my app, gets redirected to gmail for login and then grants access for "google drive" scopes to my app. My app then consumes the user access token to invoke google drive APIs using their java sdk.

I have uploaded MS word doc and a text file on source drive, I am trying to transfer the ownership of both to my another gmail account using my app. I am able to transfer the ownership of .doc file using my code but it fails for .txt file. I tried to simulate this operation using "TRY API" https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create and see the same error.

```
Error:
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request. User message: \"You can't change the owner of this item.\""
```

```
 Permission newOwnerPermission = new Permission();
 newOwnerPermission.setEmailAddress(newOwnerEmail);
 newOwnerPermission.setType("user");
 newOwnerPermission.setRole("owner"); 
 driveService.permissions().create(fileId,newOwnerPermission).setTransferOwnership(true).execute();
```

I can make my another gmail account a "writer" on txt file but not an "owner" - using either java code or google's "try api".
Do I need to change something based on mimeType in my request? I don't see anything obvious in docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The transfer of ownership - be it from the UI or programatically is only possible under the following [conditions](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494892):

> You can only transfer ownership of files and folders to someone in your organization.

[And:](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1247799?hl=en)

> As an administrator, you can change a file's owner in Google Drive, but only among accounts managed by the same organization.

In other words, neither the user himself, nor the admin can transfer ownership of a file to a diffrent gmail account - that is outside the domain.

You can easily verify it by trying to transfer ownershipi of a file from the UI - you will see the following message:

> Sorry, ownership can only be transferred to another user in the same organisation as the current owner.

### Workaround:

The only feasible way to transfer ownership of a file from user A to user B from a different domain / consumer gmail account is:

- User A makes user B an editor
- User B makes a copy of the shared file
- User B make suser A an editor of the copy
- The original file can be deleted now
- Effectively, the ownership has been transfered from user A to user B through creating a copy of the original file.